# GitHub Action is being killed

Tags: python, github-actions, pycaret

I'm running a little python project to collect data.
It's being triggered by a scheduled GitHub Action script (every midnight).
As part of expanding the project I've added the `pycaret` library to the project.
So currently installing the requirements for the project is taking about 15 minutes, plus running the python project is another 10 minutes. But the interesting part is that now the action/job is being killed with:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/bad86621-8542-4ea5-ae93-6f59b7ee2463.sh: line 1:  4382 Killed  
   python main.py 
Error: Process completed with exit code 137.
```

Now i'vew tried looking up the reason for the process being killed by i have found nothing in GitHub Actions
i'm running the job on
ubuntu-latest machine in GitHub actions.
i've set the job timeout to 60 minutes , so i don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Exit code 137 = Out of memory. Therefore I guess your implementation makes the runner (ou docker container) runs out of memory.

Comment: thanks , it was my guess but i wasn't sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Error 137` indicates that the container (runner/build agent) that builds your  project received SIGKILL and terminated.
It can be initiated manually or by the host machine when the runner exceeds its allocated memory limit.

In your case, since it is initiated by Github itself, then it is generally due to being out of memory.

*(P.S. This is a very late answer, but it may help some folks)*

Comment: Do you know what the memory limit is? I couldn't find online or in the docs what the memory limit of a standard runner is.

Answer (score 0):

Standard memory for a public repo is 16GB.
Standard Memory for a private repo is 14GB.

Memory limits can be found here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners